# Java XML Tool using method chaining/builder pattern

Tags: java, xml

I remember that a while ago I found a truly great utility here on StackOverflow for manipulating XML documents with an interface like:

```
new XMLTool(document)
    .goTo("xpath")
    .addNode("name")
    .addChild()
    .addContent("xxx")
    .parent()
    .remove("oldNode);
```

Could anybody tell me what tool that was?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [java-xmlbuilder](http://code.google.com/p/java-xmlbuilder/) at Google code? It's indeed great in use.

Comment: No that isn't the one I'm looking for. This one had full method names and featured XPath searches. 
XMLBuilder does look like a pretty great tool, even though I don't like the e().a().t() stuff.

Comment: You probably missed this page? http://code.google.com/p/java-xmlbuilder/wiki/ExampleUsage

Answer (score 1):

You've got to be kidding me. It's actually called XMLTool.

I must've had a brainfart while searching for it!

This is the URL: http://code.google.com/p/xmltool/

At least the next time someone searches for method chaining XML tool he'll find this post ...